# Select menu not displaying correctly after option removal - jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a select menu in the jQuery Mobile style, with some options.  I am using a button which removes the selected option from the select menu, but for some reason, when I remove the option, the writing stays in the box, but the option has in fact been removed from the list, if I check the dropdown.  The code to remove the option:

```
function removeOption(){
$('#items option:selected').remove().selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

This does remove the option, but the writing displayed on the box stays there until a different option is selected.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeOption(){
$('#items option:selected').remove();
$('#items').selectmenu('refresh', true);
}
```

Managed to make it work using the code above.